# Code signing "PryntTrimmerView.framework" failed

Tags: ios

I am getting the following message when uploading the project to iTunes Connect

> Code signing PryntTrimmerView.framework failed.

I have used `YPImagePicker` in my project, it has dependency on `PryntTrimmerView.framework`. I have manually added this in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason of this error.
But following command worked for me.

```
 lipo -remove i386 PryntTrimmerView -o PryntTrimmerView && lipo -remove x86_64 PryntTrimmerView -o PryntTrimmerView
```

After using this command I am able to upload build on TestFlight, but not able to run project on simulator.